# Best way to alter nullable type, if not null, but return null if null already

Tags: .net, nullable

this sort of thing comes up all the time,

this works but is ugly:

```
DateTime? firstDay = null;
if (Day.HasValue) firstDay = Day.Value.AddDays(-14);
```

this won't work:

DateTime? firstDay = Day.HasValue ? Day.Value.AddDays(-14) : null;

unless:

```
DateTime? firstDay = Day.HasValue ? Day.Value.AddDays(-14) : (DateTime?)null;
```

Maybe there should be another operator!

```
DateTime? firstDay = Day ??? Day.Value.AddDays(-14);
```

Comment: I agree!  I usually resort to using an 'if' statement and am never happy with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with:

`DateTime? firstDay = Day.HasValue ? Day.Value.Add(-14) : Day;`

Answer (score 5):

You could add an extension method to `Nullable<T>`

```
public static Nullable<T> TransformIfNotNull<T>(this Nullable<T> value,
                                                Func<T, T> transformer)
    where T : struct
{
    return value == null ? value : transformer(value.Value);
}
```

Then:

```
DateTime? firstDay = Day.TransformIfNotNull(x => x.AddDays(-14));
```

Note that although your version using the `null` literal doesn't work without casting, you could use:

```
DateTime? firstDay = Day.HasValue ? Day.Value.AddDays(-14) : Day;
```

... assuming you know `Day` won't change type between calls, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Since [all operations on nullable types are null-propagating except concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb981315(v=vs.80).aspx), you could use:

```
DateTime? Day = ...; 
...
DateTime? firstDay = Day + TimeSpan.FromDays(-14);
```